# Is this unsafe C++ code safe in Python?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Suppose I do something like:

```
retVal = MyClass().MyClassFunc()
```

The equivalent In C++ would be the creation of a temporary `MyClass` instance, which would be destroyed once the `MyClassFunc` function returns.

Now, if the `MyClassFunc` function returns a reference to some non-static member variable of the `MyClass` class, then this code is generally unsafe.

My question is whether or not this code is safe in Python.

More specifically, I am interested in the safety of:

```
db = MongoClient(uri).get_database(db_name)
```

But I am looking for the general answer of course.

Comment: Are you worried about the fact that the object is garbage collected?

Comment: Python references are more akin to ref-counted pointers. The above is safe and fairly idiomatic Python.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Yes, precisely!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: It is safe (given you worry about garbage collection).

> Now, if the MyClassFunc function returns a reference to some non-static member variable of the `MyClass` class, then this code is generally unsafe.

I assume that you are worried that since you allocated the `MyClass` object on the stack, it will be removed once you return from that method.

In Python however *conceptually* there exists no heap at stack. You allocate objects, and the Python virtual machine should handle them such that - as long as these are alive - the are not collected by the garbage collector.

So given you return a reference to a member of the `MyClass` object, at least that member will still be alive. If that member is a non-static method, it will usually have a reference to the object and so the `MyClass` object will be alive as well.

In Python garbage collection is done in a transparent manner, like C#, etc. So you do not have to worry about memory management: you can assume that if you refer to an object, it will always be alive anyway.

For instance one can sometimes find things like:

```
getter = {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 5}.get
```

So here we obtain a reference to the `get` method of that dictionary. We can no longer reference the original dictionary, but internally, the `.get` method will keep the dictionary alive.

Comment: As an aside, `import sys; sys.getrefcount(var)` should always be > 1 (meaning actual refcount >= 1) for a variable to exist.